# How do I configure the Spark Job Server in DSE to queue jobs until resources are available?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector, spark-jobserver

We are using DataStax Enterprise which has support for Spark and Spark Job server.

We have 3 node olap casandra cluster with each node configuration of 8 core processor and 32G of RAM

As far our spark job is concerned with above configuration I was able to run at most 4 spark job in parallel with low latency.

I am using pre-created spark context to submit the job via spark job server api , also Built In Spark Job server has a limit of submitting 8 spark at once in parallel and it start rejecting the job as soon as the more jobs are getting submitted.

I need a mechanism in which my spark job should only process 4 job at any moment of time and rest of the spark job should remain in queue till the time any of the spark job is fixed and we have slot available for it to process.

How can I acheive this on DSE Cassandra with Spark built in or In normal spark way ?

I am not aware about how put a queuing mechanism on spark cluster and how can I control with different parameter.

DSE spark have its own resource manager and doesn't have any MESOS or YARN functionality thorugh which i guess we can submit the job to a particular queue.

Comment: Hello, what's the version of DSE you're running with? You could run `./dse -v` to find that (or) get that from logs. Also, if you're on a supported licensing model, you could ask this directly at [DataStax Support portal](https://support.datastax.com) yourself.

Comment: we are using 6.8.12.

Answer (score 0):

DataStax Enterprise (DSE) ships with open-source [Spark Job Server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) for clusters running with the DSE Analytics workload. Specifically, DSE 6.8.12 [ships with Spark Job Server v0.8.0](https://github.com/datastax/release-notes/blob/master/DSE_6.8_Release_Notes.md#components-versions-for-dse-6812).

The queueing mechanism you've asked for is not a feature available in the Job Server.

In any case, the Job Server simply provides a REST API for submitting jobs to a Spark cluster. It is the Spark master's role to coordinate and manage Spark applications, requesting resources (CPUs, memory) from Spark worker nodes to execute jobs.

If there are insufficient resources available (not enough CPUs, memory, or both) then the submitted Spark application will wait in the queue until resources become available.

If you think that Spark applications are taking up too much memory or CPUs on a node, consider lowering the amount of resources available to worker nodes by setting the relevant Spark worker options in `dse.yaml`. For details, see [Configuring Spark nodes in DataStax Enterprise](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkConfiguration.html). Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick ....Thanks for the input .......Is the queue inside spark is infinite in size and holds the data till spark job is picked for execution ? Also Spark job server built in DSE has this limit of max-job-per-context which is 8 .... I cannot submit more than 8 spark job via spark job server and even if i would be able to increase this limit , would that be a good approach to submit the spark job on same spark context ?

Comment: I'll provide a quick answer but please post a new question, otherwise the comments section becomes a never-ending thread.  Specifically for DSE Analytics, there is a high-availability feature in DSE that persists the state of submitted applications so when a node goes down the job is rescheduled on another worker. This same functionality can hold an unlimited number of jobs in theory. Cheers!